# Will backing up a game CD/DVD work like this?

Tags: linux, backup, dvd

I recently heard that CDs and DVDs "go bad" after extended periods of time. Initially this was a problem for me because I couldn't write boot disks for new Linux distributions (at least until I get new writeable disks), but then I remembered some Windows games I have that might become unreadable by the time I get access to a Windows system again.

I decided to make compressed backup files using this command line:

```
dd if=/dev/cdrom | lrzip -l -H -o output.lzo
```

I've never actually done this before, and I can't test it, so I just want to know if I will be able to write this image to a new disk if the old one stops working.

Now that I've asked, I wonder how I'll be able to write it too. Will de-compressing this image result in an ISO file that I can write with `wodim`, or will I need some other method?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After further research I discovered that using `dd` to copy CDs is actually a very common practice. Normally people direct the output to a file with the `.iso` extention and set the block size to the disk's block size, but technically I *was* creating an LZO-compressed ISO file.

Now that I know this, I advise anyone who was in the same position I was in when I asked this question to use this command line instead:

```
dd if=/dev/cdrom of=/path/to/image.iso bs=2048
```

Creating the ISO file without immediately compressing it allows an opportunity to check the file's integrity first. In my original command line, I was using LZO compression because I heard it was faster than copying; I may have been mislead there, because the reader still operated in bursts. Either way, I now plan to compress in a second step.

The `bs` option seems to be mostly a formality, but matching the block size of the medium (which can be found by running `isoinfo` on the device) is generally a good practice.

If the disk is damaged and parts of it won't read, the program `ddrescue` can be used in place of `dd`. Without any extra options it should recover more data than `dd`. It also has more advanced options that could help in more serious situations, and would then be worth researching.

EDIT: `ddrescue` (or perhaps just the GNU version of ddrescue) now uses a different command-line structure than it did when my first source here was written, so it can't be simply swapped in to replace `dd`. It isused more like `ddrescue -b 2048 /dev/cdrom /path/to/image.iso /path/to/log.log`

sources:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/linux/answers/Applications_GUI_Multimedia/How_To_Do_Eveything_With_DD?s=9f6a3b4e664ac979e8d3a1643ca253f5

http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/archiving-cds-iso-commandline

Comment: The second source you list specifically says not to do what you are suggesting in the section called "Why dd if= of= is a bad idea".

Comment: @RyanTM If you had read it, you would know that it only says to add the `bs` and `count` arguments. I added one in my solution, and the other isn't recommended by any other source, nor does there seem to be a reason for it. Other sources say that `dd` does both automatically. Now, did you just downvote my question because of a personal problem with my answer? Tantrums don't help anyone...

Comment: I didn't downvote your question or answer.

Comment: @RyanTM Then I apologize for accusing you. Unfortunately whoever did downvote it didn't have the decency to identify themselves or explain why.

Answer (score 1):

First, the simplest thing to do is to just use dd. So, skip the compression until you have it working with dd by itself.

```
dd if=/dev/cdrom of=/path/to/good_name_of_cdrom.img bs=64k
```

Then you should be able to test this img to make sure it copied well.

```
mkdir /path/to/mount_point/
mount -o loop /path/to/good_name_of_cdrom.img /path/to/mount_point/
cd /path/to/mount_point/
```

The files on the cdrom should be available at the `/path/to/mount_point`.

Comment: I asked a dumb question here. +1 for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I take that back. You just confused me.

Comment: It seems like the ISO file format is not well defined, so I'm probably wrong that it is strictly not a ISO file.